# Thrift server facade for clients

Tags: python, design-patterns, thrift

I am having a little trouble with a server / client design and
wonder if anyone had any advice.

I have a Thrift server that abstracts a data store.  The idea is that
there will be a number of clients that are essentially
out of process plugins that use the interface provided by the server
to receive, manipulate the underlying data store and also provide
their own data.
There will be a number of other clients which simply access the data
provided by the server and its "plugins".

The  problem case is when one of these "plugins" wishes to provide its
own data and provide an interface to that data.
The server should have no knowledge of the plugins data or interface.

I would ideally like all clients to access functionality through the
main thrift server so it acts as a facade for the plugins. If a client
requested some data provided by a plugin the main server could
delegate to the plugin to provide that data. I guess this would mean
have each plugin being a thrift client and server. I have written the
server in python so could probably handle thrift calls that are not
yet defined but would it be possible to forward these calls another
thrift server IE act as a proxy ?

An alternative is maybe have the plugins be clients only and push data
to the server. But the format of these messages
would unknown to the server and would have to be generic enough to
accommodate different types of data. I not sure how I would provide a
useful interface to this data to other clients.

As far as I can see only the plugins knows how to store and manipulate
the data it owns so this idea probably would not work.

Thanks for any advice. Any suggestions welcomed.

Comment: To clarify the nomenclature used here: Is a **plugin** a Thrift service (with associated python code-gen) hosted within the Thrift server? Does a **client** use code generated from a particular plugin, but is actually a client to the Thrift server?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need some sort of a mechanism to correlate requests to the different plugins available. Ideally, there should be a different URL path per set of operations published for each plugin.

I would consider implementing a sort of map/dictionary of URL paths to plugins. Then for each request received, do a lookup in the map and get the associated plugin and send it the request accordingly. If there is no entry in the map, then a redirect/proxy could be sent. For example if URL = `http://yourThriftServer/path/operation`, the operation or the path ***and*** operation would map to a plugin.

An extra step would be to implement a sort of meta request, whereby a client could query what URL paths/operations are available in the server.